# Starting minute in minute data aggregation in xts

Tags: r, xts

I have a question about xts `to.hourly` and `split` methods. It seems that it assumes that if my timestamp is 12:00 that it means a minute 12:00-12:01. However my data provider has 11:59-12:00 in mind. I didn't find any parameters on this. Is the only solution to simply lag my time series by one minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually about the `endpoints` function, which is what `to.hourly`, `split.xts`, and several other functions use to define intervals.

The `endpoints` function "assumes" that your timestamps are actual datetimes, and a time of 12:00:00 is the *beginning* of the 12 o'clock hour. If your data have 1-minute resolution, a time of 12:00:00 falls in the interval of 12:00:00.0-12:00:59.999.

There is no parameter you can change to make xts behave as if a time of 12:00:00 means anything other than what it actually is.

If you're certain that your data provider is putting a timestamp of 12:00 on data that occur in the interval of 11:59:00.0-11:59:59.999, then you might be able to simply subtract a small value from the xts object index.

```
# assuming 'x' is your xts object
.index(x) <- .index(x) - 0.001
```

That said, you need to think carefully about doing this because making a mistake can cause you to have look-ahead bias.